# Running a macro on a local PC - Excel file in sharepoint

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, refresh

I have an macro in Excel designed to refresh all data when opening the file, as well as update it every 30 minutes - this works as it should. The file is in a SharePoint folder, so that myself and my colleagues can access it at the same time.

My issue is that that I need the macro to *only* run on my PC, and not everyone else who has the file open. The reason for this is a long explanation, but essentially they are not able to update the data. If they do try to update it, error messages will appear.

Can anyone help with limiting the macro to only run on my PC, by somehow recognising me? Other ideas? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Dim RunTimer As Date
Sub Refresh()
RunTimer = Now + TimeValue("00:30:00")
Application.OnTime RunTimer, "Refresh"
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
End Sub

Macro which starts the routine when opening the file:
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call Refresh
End Sub

This macro is based on the tutorial by "Computergaga" on YouTube.
```

Comment: You can check the computer name with environ("computername")  and the username with `environ("username")`

Comment: Have the file on your machine, updated b y your script. Then have a Chron job that copies it to the shared location every 30 minutes or after an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are logged in Excel then you could use:

```
If Application.UserName = "joachimu" then
    Call Refresh
End If
```

Alternatively instead `Application.UserName` you could use `Environ("username")`